Wikipedia API allpages generator returns duplicate titles
I have an issue while trying to download all the page titles in Wikipedia:
I'm using a generator=allpages in order to download all of the article titles and using the clcontinue parameter to get the next page but unfortunately, in the response, I often get titles that has been already returned.
I need to know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a problem on the API side.
What I do is a request with these parameters:
GET https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&gapnamespace=0&gapfilterredir=nonredirects&gaplimit=500&prop=description|categories&converttitles=true&format=json&origin=*

Then, in the response, I read the continue object which contains a clcontinue field and I append the value of that field in the next request, like this:
GET https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&gapnamespace=0&gapfilterredir=nonredirects&gaplimit=500&prop=description|categories&converttitles=true&format=json&origin=*&clcontinue=3089896|Senza_fonti_-_luglio_2017

Apparently when I do this, the results I get are the same as the previous request, but at a certain point I get a new field in the continue object which is gapcontinue, then I use it in the next request like this:
GET https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&gapnamespace=0&gapfilterredir=nonredirects&gaplimit=500&prop=description|categories&converttitles=true&format=json&origin=*gapcontinue=%27Na_santarella

and I finally get new results.
I'm probably using the continue wrong here, but from the documentation I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Can someone give me a hand please? Thanks in advance!

Ok, I found out that the clcontinue refers to the categories of a specific page. In fact, the value is <page-id>|<category-name> if I'm not mistaken. So I think that when I do the next request with the clcontinue parameter, I will get the continuation of the categories of that page and the rest of the response will be the same.

This isn't answering your question, but if you are trying to get every article title, you should not be using the API, but the dumps instead: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/itwiki/20240720/
Here are all the page titles in a 40MB file: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/itwiki/20240720/itwiki-20240720-all-titles.gz
The article titles in that file are where page_namespace is 0.

That's a huge piece of information, thanks! Unfortunately, I also want the API to return a short description of the item and the categories it is in. That's why I set the prop to description|categories.
